# ionic LazyLoad Failed to instantiate module starter

Tags: android, ionic-framework, lazy-loading

I try to use ionic -image - lazy -load but get an error every application displays a blank page.

Here is my code:

```
   <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js"></script>
<script src="js/ionic-image-lazy-load.js"></script>
```

controller.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ionicLazyLoad'])
```

the error:

```
ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
```

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionicLazyLoad due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ionicLazyLoad' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=ionicLazyLoad
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8895:12)
    at http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10785:17
    at ensure (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10709:38)
    at module (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10783:14)
    at http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13189:22
    at forEach (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13190:40
    at forEach (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=ionicLazyLoad&p1=Er…%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.42%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13173%3A5)
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8895:12)
    at http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13212:15
    at forEach (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13190:40
    at forEach (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13190:40
    at forEach (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter.controllers…%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.42%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13173%3A5)
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8895:12)
    at http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13212:15
    at forEach (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13190:40
    at forEach (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at createInjector (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13099:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10457:20)
    at bootstrap (http://10.0.0.42:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10478:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3A…3A%2F%2F10.0.0.42%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10478%3A12)REGEX_STRING_REGEXP @ ionic.bundle.js:8895(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:13212forEach @ ionic.bundle.js:9163loadModules @ ionic.bundle.js:13173createInjector @ ionic.bundle.js:13099doBootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:10457bootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:10478angularInit @ ionic.bundle.js:10372(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:37186trigger @ ionic.bundle.js:11823eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:12098

Comment: is your ionic-image-lazy-load.js file located inside the js folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please double check whether you have downloaded a correct JS file.

[ionic-image-lazy-load.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paveisistemas/ionic-image-lazy-load/master/ionic-image-lazy-load.js)